# Is there a time function its result is guaranteed to change every time is called?

Tags: c++, windows, synchronization

I tought it was GetTickCount64() until I tried this:

```
#include <fstream>
#include <windows.h>
#include <iostream>

void doSomething();

int main() {
srand(GetTickCount64());
std::fstream file;
file.open("test.dat", std::ios_base::out | std::ios_base::trunc);

    for (;;)
        file <<std::boolalpha<<(GetTickCount64()==GetTickCount64()) << std::endl;
}
```

And this:

```
#include <fstream>
#include <windows.h>
#include <iostream>

void doSomething();

int main() {
srand(GetTickCount64());
std::fstream file;
file.open("test.dat", std::ios_base::out | std::ios_base::trunc);

__int64 a, b;
for (;;) {
    a = GetTickCount64();
    doSomething();
    b = GetTickCount64();
    file <<std::boolalpha<<(a==b) << std::endl;
    }
}

void doSomething() {
int T=(see below);
    for (int i = 0; i < (rand() % T); i++)
        __noop;
}
```

With the 1st variant i received 1 false every 200.000 true (806642 iterations).

With the second variant and T=5 i received 1 false every 90000 true (627018 iterations), with T=1000 I received 1 false every 4444 true (693361 iterations).

So it is absolutely not giving different values every time is called. I need to create a timestamp in a shared memory area, and I had a lot of fun trying to guess why the program wasn't working!

What function I can use instead?
 Thanks!

**Edit** to clarify: I understand that a timer simply can't have an infinite accuracy, but I was wondering if exists a timer that is accurate enough to be faster than the cpu (yes, probably it's an absurd question but I have only a vague idea about how timers works).

Btw you're right, I'll use some random function for generate an unique number and I'll store the time in another place.

Comment: before we start ranting about "this is not what ticks are meant for", can you perhaps elaborate why you need to rely on them in your shared memory synchronization concept? perhaps there's a better way to do what you need.

Comment: Sorry, is not for synchronization purpose despite what I wrote in the question (I'm not english). I need just a quick way to check if the memory is changed, I'm using semaphore for IPC synchronization.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since you only care about the value being monotonically increasing, and don't (apparently) care about how much difference there is between one and the next, it seems like [InterlockedIncrement64](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms683615.aspx) would work for you.

From there it's a simple matter of ensuring that all the code that needs the serial number gets access to the same location. Windows has a couple of ways of doing that, but you haven't really told us enough about what you're doing/how you're using this to give meaningful advice about which will fit your needs the best.

Comment: I choose this because is the easiest and it is thread safe, but I guess there are other solutions right too.

Answer (score 5):

You might want to look at QueryPerformanceCounter:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dn553408%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

For example:

```
LARGE_INTEGER li;
QueryPerformanceCounter(&li);
```

It's not, however, "guaranteed to change every time it's called"...

Comment: I agree, `QueryPerformanceCounter` has a lower resolution than any other time function: http://www.drdobbs.com/windows/win32-performance-measurement-options/184416651?pgno=4

Answer (score 4):

The short answer is no, because Timers never have an infinite accuracy. i.e. you will always be limited by the accuracy of the underlying timer.

`GetTickCount` in particular, has a [limited accuracy](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee417693.aspx) that explains your observation:

> The resolution of the GetTickCount function is limited to the
>   resolution of the system timer, which is typically in the range of 10
>   milliseconds to 16 milliseconds. The resolution of the GetTickCount
>   function is not affected by adjustments made by the
>   GetSystemTimeAdjustment function.

Microsoft [recommends](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee417693.aspx) the usage of Performance Counter if your system supports high resolution timers:

- [QueryPerformanceCounter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms886788.aspx)
- [QueryPerformanceFrequency](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms886788.aspx)

On this helpful tutorial, Microsoft acknowledge the limited accuracy of the timers:

> Windows has and will continue to invest in providing a reliable and
>   efficient performance counter. When you need time stamps with a
>   resolution of 1 microsecond or better and you don't need the time
>   stamps to be synchronized to an external time reference, choose
>   QueryPerformanceCounter or KeQueryPerformanceCounter. When you need
>   UTC-synchronized time stamps with a resolution of 1 microsecond or
>   better, choose GetSystemTimePreciseAsFileTime or
>   KeQuerySystemTimePrecise.

If you only care about a monotonic function, you could get your own counter (the number of possible different output being limited by the range of the data type used to count, here a ulong long, for instance)

e.g.:

```
static unsigned long GetNext()
{
    static unsigned long long counter;
    return counter++;
}
```

Of course your calls to this counter would need to be synchronized on multi threaded programs, typically with an `InterlockedIncrement`

Answer (score 4):

You could read the time stamp counter with __rdtsc() (MSVC)

As it's a processor registry which counts the number of clock cycles since reset, it's impossible that two near calls return the same value.

However, it's not in seconds, but in clock cycles, so it's not simple to convert it to real time, especially with varying clock speeds (modern processors, however, guarantee a constant frequency update for RDTSC, this is checkable with the CPUID)

Also, on early multi-core processors, this value is not synced between cores (checkable with the CPUID). Also on multiprocessor systems. So the behavior across multiple threads may depend on hardware.

Comment: This can run into a problem: the same thread can (and often will) be scheduled on different cores/processors at different times. Therefore, it could run on one core at one time, returning a TSC value. Then it runs on another core later, and the TSC is far enough out of sync to return the same value again. It's quite unlikely on any given run, but if you use it long enough, its happening becomes *nearly* inevitable.

Answer (score 0):

What about [CoCreateGuid](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms688568%28VS.85%29.aspx) assuming Windows? I'm sure there's a similar method on other platforms. UPDATE: not sure ... maybe you're looking for a time and not uniqueness.